# cvs broken on MacOs-Catalina? (cannot get working directory)

Tags: cvs, macos-catalina

I've just upgraded my Mac to Catalina and cvs does not seem to be working.  Almost every command I try gives me a variant on the error:

```
cvs [init aborted]: cannot get working directory: No such file or directory
```

This is true not just for existing repositories, but if I try to set up a new repository or a new cvsroot (as above).

I've tried re-installing cvs via Homebrew but the problem remains.

Is anyone else experiencing this and does anyone have suggestions for workarounds?  (Obviously I could shift this stuff to git or similar, but its mostly legacy projects and I'm not that enthusiastic to go to the effort)

Comment: I'm seeing the same error but only with iCloud folders.

Answer (score 6):

In case you have homebrew:

```
brew remove cvs
brew install cvs
```

did the trick for me. The new binary will be in ***/usr/local/bin/cvs***, make sure you call that binary and not the catalina one (in */usr/bin/cvs*)
Simply typing "brew update; brew upgrade" - what you should do after an OS upgrade - will not be enough.

Comment: This answer by digital hippie worked perfectly on my MacBook Air running OS X 10.15.4.  I checked after brew finished the install with which cvs and it was pointing correctly to /uer/local/bin/cvs.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`cannot get working directory` only exists one place in the CVS source code, so was pretty easy to track it down to something awry in `xgetcwd()`. `xgetcwd()` eventually calls `getcwd()`, but apparently isn't using the version defined in `unistd.h` in Catalina, but its own version from `"getcwd.h"` which is included in the `CVS` source.

I don't have the time to track down why it works pre-Catalina, but the following patch forces the issue and worked for me on 10.15.

```
--- cvs-1.12.13/lib/xgetcwd.c.orig      2019-10-10 22:52:37.000000000 -0500
+++ cvs-1.12.13/lib/xgetcwd.c   2019-10-10 22:53:32.000000000 -0500
@@ -26,8 +26,9 @@

 #include <errno.h>
 #include <limits.h>
+#include <unistd.h>

-#include "getcwd.h"
+/* #include "getcwd.h" */
 #include "xalloc.h"

 /* Return the current directory, newly allocated.
```

Comment: Sadly homebrew doesn't seem to have stored the source anywhere - I guess I'm going to have to look into doing my own install of cvs.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with CVS from Homebrew.
CVS from macports fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

As an temporary solution you can use Java version of cvs client command from Netbeans https://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/downloads/. Simple script

```
#!/bin/bash
java -Dcvs.root=$CVSROOT -jar org-netbeans-lib-cvsclient.jar $@
```

works almost exactly identical as original cvs command. It is not optimal solution, but works.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't like my CVSROOT for some reason and is throwing IllegalArgumentException's at me.